# Lots of perl (and others) errors with a lots of commands

Tags: perl

I don't know what happen , but since yesterday afternoon , a lot of command  in my pi (using raspmc) return me a lot of perl errors and weird others errors , eg:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/etc/init.d/apache2: 110: /etc/init.d/apache2: pidof: Input/output error
/etc/init.d/apache2: 110: /etc/init.d/apache2: pidof: Input/output error
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
.
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gitweb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 454 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main gitweb all 1:1.7.10.4-1+wheezy1+rpi1 [454 kB]
Fetched 454 kB in 8s (52.2 kB/s)                                                     
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/IO/Handle.pm line 9
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/IO/Handle.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/IO/Handle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/IO/Seekable.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/IO/Seekable.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/IO/File.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/IO/File.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.14/FileHandle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 3.
) -- aborting
(Reading database ... 31830 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gitweb 1:1.7.10.4-1+wheezy1+rpi1 (using .../gitweb_1%3a1.7.10.4-1+wheezy1+rpi1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gitweb ...
Setting up gitweb (1:1.7.10.4-1+wheezy1+rpi1) ...
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/etc/init.d/apache2: 110: /etc/init.d/apache2: pidof: Input/output error
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried reinstall perl , nothing change , dpkg --configure -a neither.

The last things I'd done before this to happen is installing gitweb and openvpn (and configure it).

The "ation_short_name" look a lot like a typo error but i don't know how this could happen..

Does someone have an idea of what happen here ?

Edit: When i use

```
$ echo test
```

it output "test" , but when using

```
$ /bin/echo test
```

it throw the "/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: ation_short_name: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Edit2: I reinstalled coreutils , I no longer have the /bin/echo issue but the perl one is still here
"

Comment: Enough space left on disk?

Comment: i checked that , the sd is not full (90% used , so on a 4g sd that mean around 400MB, enough to install perl i guess)

Answer (score 1):

Well , It just seem that my SD was very corrupted , fsck on a computer showed and fixed a lot of errors. And without surprise , I was unable to boot the rpi using this sdcard again.

I thought the sdcard being corrupted happened only to those who OC the rpi , seems like I was wrong.

Anyway , this time on reinstall, I put root fs on a usb key, so hopefully no longer corrupted issue.

Comment: IME it mostly depends on the card, maybe the kernel. I have one (OEM) that would just ignore changes to files sometimes. Switching cards (to Transcend) helped.